# Проблема с рендерингом списков в React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Пытаюсь вытащить из API сервиса данные и вставить их в компонент.

Вот код:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      dataObj : {}
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {

    fetch("https://api.topvisor.ru/v2/json/get/positions_2/history", {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'User-Id'       : '11111',
        'Authorization' : '5b10f6bf67f433e2fa0c',
        'Content-type'  : 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        'group_folder_id_depth' : 1,
        'project_id'            : 561448,
        'regions_indexes'       : [76],
        'fields'                : ['name','id','tags','target','group_name'],
        'type_range'            : 2,
        'date1'                 : '2018-06-25',
        'date2'                 : '2018-07-04',
        'count_dates'           : 31,
        'limit'                 : 100,
        'offset'                : 0,
        'show_headers'          : 1,
        'show_exists_dates'     : 1,
        'show_visitors'         : 1,
        'show_top_by_depth'     : 10,
      })
    })
    .then(response => {
      response.json();
     })
    .then(data => {
      let objcts = data.results.map((obj) => {
        return (
          <li key={obj.results}>
            {obj.results.keywords.name}
          </li>
        )
      })
      this.setState({dataObj: data});
      console.log('state' + this.state.dataObj);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ul>

        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Ошибки:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined
```

Для кода:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      dataObj : {}
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {

    fetch("https://api.topvisor.ru/v2/json/get/positions_2/history", {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'User-Id'       : '44583',
        'Authorization' : '5b80f6bf27f633e4fa0c',
        'Content-type'  : 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        'group_folder_id_depth' : 1,
        'project_id'            : 561448,
        'regions_indexes'       : [76],
        'fields'                : ['name','id','tags','target','group_name'],
        'type_range'            : 2,
        'date1'                 : '2018-06-25',
        'date2'                 : '2018-07-04',
        'count_dates'           : 31,
        'limit'                 : 100,
        'offset'                : 0,
        'show_headers'          : 1,
        'show_exists_dates'     : 1,
        'show_visitors'         : 1,
        'show_top_by_depth'     : 10,
      })
    })
    .then(response => {
      response.json();
     })
    .then(data => {
      let objcts = data.results.map((obj) => {
        return (
          <li key={obj.results}>
          </li>
        )
      })
      this.setState({dataObj: data});
      console.log('state' + this.state.dataObj);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ul>
          {this.state.dataObj}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Ошибки:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in ul (at App.js:55)
    in div (at App.js:54)
    in App (at index.js:7)
```

Я мало чего соображаю в React, поэтому подскажите хотя бы ссылочки, где можно было бы подсмотреть. Готовое решение тоже хорошо)

Comment: Я мало что соображаю в экстрасенсорике, поэтому укажите хотя бы ошибки, которые вы получаете

Comment: Так в чем вопрос то? Какие ошибки выскакивают? Что хочется увидеть? Пустой рендер естественно ничего не покажет

Comment: @RomanDanilov, исправил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Первое**: у вас ошибка в синтаксисе

```
.then(response => {
  response.json();
 })
```

Это стрелочная функция и в вашем случае они ничего не возвращает

```
// либо так
.then(response => {
  return response.json();
})
// либо так
.then(response => response.json())
```

**Второе**: ну в общем, я не понимаю, зачем задавать конкретный вопрос про технологию, которую ты в принципе не понимаешь? Можно потратить один день на то что бы почитать про `React` и тогда второй ошибки не было бы. 
`React` не умеет просто так выводить объекты: либо строка, либо компонент, либо `null`. 
Поэтому как-то парсите ваше объект и выводите отдельными св-вами, либо пишите компонент, который принимает ваш `dataObj` и уже там делает с ним то, что нужно

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul>
        // если someProp строка, то вот так можно
        {this.state.dataObj.someProp}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Вот при обработке данных вы создаете массив, но потом не используете его

```
  let objcts = data.results.map((obj) => {
    return (
      <li key={obj.results}>
      </li>
    )
  })
```

Делайте тоже самое в рендере и выводите именно этот массив

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul>
        {data.results.map((obj) =>
           <li key={obj.id}>{obj.prop}</li>
        )}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```